# How do you show that $\lim_{k\to\infty}(\frac{x^k}{k!} S^{(k)}(c_k)) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

The functions $S$ and $C$ are defined as follows: both are infinitely differentiable, $\frac{d}{dx}S(x) = C(x), \frac{d}{dx}C(x) = S(x)$, and $S(0) = 0, C(0) = 1$.

So, clearly the Taylor expansion of this function on the interval $[a, x]$ with $a = 0, x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c \in [|-x|, |x|]$ is $$S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\frac{x^n}{n!}S^{(0)}(0) + \frac{x^k}{k!}S^{(k)}(c)$$

**My question is** how do you show that $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}S^{(k)}(c_k) = 0$, where the term in the limit is the remainder term in the Taylor expansion of $S(x)$, and each $c_k$ is between $0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

**This is what I've done so far:** I have determined that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!} = 0$, so all that remains is to prove that $\lim_{k\to\infty} S^{(k)}(c_k)$ *exists*. This is where I'm having trouble.

I've attempted to use Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem and the normal formulation of Mean Value Theorem to come up with expressions for $S^{(k)}(c_k)$, but the oscillatory nature of $S$ means I always have two different expressions for each parity of $k$. I've also tried setting maximum bounds $M_k$ for each $S^{(k)}(c_k)$, but that doesn't help either, since I have no way of knowing whether the sequence of $M_k$'s is bounded or not. What approach am I not seeing?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: $S(x) $ and $C(x) $ do not have any oscillatory nature per se. In fact, $S(x) =( e^x-e^{-x})/2 $ and $C(x) =(e^x+e^{-x})/2$ (Just solve the differential eqns. to get these). Having done that, clearly both S and C are bounded on any closed interval.

Comment: What you need is to show that $S^{(k)}$ is bounded.